# iOS provisioning profile which has both wildcard and push notification identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile

When i tried registering a provisioning profile for push notification, apple didn't allow the option to specify wildcard identifier.
Do i have to always create two provisioning profiles in my developer account? one for push and one normal identifier or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

That's because Apple has to have a unique identifier for this specific app.  The same rule applies if you try to create an app which has in-app purchases.  In both of these scenarios, wildcards are not allowed.

You have no choice but to create an explicit `ABCDEFGHIJ.com.myCompanyName.myAppNameHere` type identifier and use that as the provisioning profile's App ID for your development/distribution profiles.

Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) allows an app that isn't running in the foreground to notify the user that it has information for the user. Unlike other capabilities, you don't configure push notifications in your Xcode project. To enable push notifications, you create an explicit App ID that enables push notifications and a corresponding client SSL certificate.
>
> You can create only one explicit App ID that matches your bundle ID. Therefore, if Xcode created an explicit App ID for you—for example, when you added another capability that requires an explicit App ID—you should use it; otherwise, you create an explicit App ID that matches your bundle ID. You then generate and download a corresponding client SSL certificate—this step fully enables push notifications—and refresh provisioning profiles in Xcode. Later, you install the client SSL certificate and key on your server.